# Best option for Cloud database

Tags: android, database, firebase-realtime-database, cloud, flickr

I am going to develop an Android app where I need the following data in a cloud service:

- Store large amount of photos (+5GB)
- Save an ID + several uploaded URLs + some other information (NoSQL)

Which cloud database service do you think that fits my necesities? After searching some information I think that a good solution could be:

Firebase Realtime database (NoSQL) + Flickr (up to 1TB for free)

The idea is upload several pictures to FLickr and then store the information in Firebase like: id / URL_1 / URL_2 / URL_3 / Value / (...)

I think that it is the cheaper option that fits my necesities. What do you think? It is my first time using this type of services and I do not want to start and realize after a month that this solution is not correct.

Thank you very much.

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: This is what I have done, I'm describing my problem and what I have found to solve it. I'm asking if this is a good solution or I'm missing something.